# Order of books by Rick Riordan

Tags: reading-order, rick-riordan, percy-jackson-and-the-olympians

Where does the book called Demigods and Magicians where Percy Jackson and Annabeth Chase meet the Kane siblings fit into the chronological order of the Rick Riordan books? Also where does the book called Percy Jackson (The Olympians) The Demigod Files fit into the chronological order of the Rick Riordan books?